# Transportation and cost to get to Tay Ninh from Ho Chi Minh City?

Tags: transportation, vietnam, ho-chi-minh-city, tay-ninh

If coming from Ho Chi Minh City, what is the fastest mode of transportation I can take to go to Export Processing Zone and Industrial Park in Tay Ninh and how much will it cost?

I've been searching for this on Google but I still cannot find a suitable answer.

Comment: What have you found on google so far?

Comment: This is what i found an all day return trip from Ho Chi Minh City to Tay Ninh and Cu Chi would cost you about forty five dollars in United States money. This is chartered taxi, but my purpose is to go direct to tay ninh industrial park for some business engagement. I still could not find buses or maybe because I do not know the place and bus station.

Comment: @user8300: You should really include such information in your question so we know where the bar is set and what to aim for.

Comment: Just want a direct transportation from ho chi minh to tay ninh industrial park no side trip and how much it cost. thank you

Answer (score 3):

According to google maps, the location you want to go to, is called the "[J.V Corporation. for Development & Management of Export Processing Zone Sai Gon Linh Trung](http://goo.gl/maps/4mkJ4)" in Tay Ninh province. This is a bit out of Ho Chih Minh city, and it will be difficult to get there with a bus, and impossible with a direct one.

There are two bus lines going in the direction from the center, [number 13](http://agreenet.vn/xe-buyt/ben-thanh-ben-xe-cu-chi-1097/) and [number 94](http://agreenet.vn/xe-buyt/ben-xe-cho-lon-ben-xe-cu-chi-1184/). But both take you only as far as [Củ Chi](http://goo.gl/maps/b9Wb2), from there you have to take bus [70-1](http://agreenet.vn/xe-buyt/ben-xe-cu-chi-ben-xe-go-dau-1216/), which is the only bus that stops at the Trảng Bàng bus station ("Bến xe Trảng Bàng"), not too far from where you want to go.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you know Ben Thanh bus station ( opposite to benthanh market). In here, catching the bus number 703( tour from benthanh to Moc bai), this bus will stop at Moc Bai bus station. And in here let catch the bus number 05 to Tay Ninh. You could catch this bus in Ben Thanh at 6AM - 16PM.

Another tour is the bus 13 from Ben thanh to Cu Chi, 94 if you are at Cho Lon bus station. You could take these bus to Cu Chi and continue catch the bus number 603 from Cu Chi bus station to Tay Ninh.

And one more way you could be there easier and exactly where you want to go to, let go to Mien Dong bus station (bus 26 from ben thanh to mien dong) and come to ticket room and buy a ticket to Tay Ninh, only 40vnd-45vnd. they would take you to the place you want in Tay Ninh.

Comment: This explanation brings you to the center of [Tây Ninh](http://goo.gl/maps/vdj9Q), not necessarily to the place where you want to go. I would verify the destination again. From the description it sounds more like he wants to go to a location in Trảng Bàng which is in Tây Ninh district, but not in it's center.

Comment: If you want to go to exactly place, you can take the third way, the last way i mentioned. i'm sure you can ask the driver to take you to your place. If it is so far, you just need pay more about 10 thousand vnd for the driver.